# Apache Rewrite Rules

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache-2.4

I have moved my website from a Wiki to Wordpress and in the process, realised that I have broken links to some popular pages on my website. Is it possible to fix this with a rewrite rule?

I need the rule to redirect anything beginning with "^/wiki/(.+)$" to "/$1" but also replacing the "_" character used in MediaWiki slugs to "-" used in Wordpress slugs.

For example:

```
http://example.com/wiki/An_Example_Page
```

should be pointed to:

```
http://example.com/an-example-page
```

Is it possible to write such a rewrite rule?

**Edit:** It appears that Wordpress doesn't even care if the "/wiki/" part is removed - provided the slug matches, and that seems to be case-insensitive too. So all I need to do is change the "_" characters to "-" in the slugs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)_(.*)$ $1-$2 [N,R=301]
```

To replace `_` by `-`

Comment: This rule should be repeated for multiple occurences of `_`, as this will one will only replace one occurrence of `_` in the URL. Also, the rule for most `_` characters should be first, and then this rule last.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen `This rule should be repeated for multiple occurences of _, as this will one will only replace one occurrence of _ in the URL.` Yes ! this is what i was thinking, but when i've tested it worked, even in case of multiple occurence of `_` (???)

Comment: It is really odd if it replaces every `_` character. That rule should only replace one occurrence.

Comment: For now, I've entered four rewrite rules: one for 2 words, 3 words, 4 words and 5 words. I may need to enter a few more, but that should catch 90% of the load. I will redirect with a 301 to ensure that search engines update and then in a few months, remove these rules.

Comment: If this helped, please mark as answered. Of course if it doesn't don't touch anything ;)